Circular Import Issue with FastAPI and Pydantic Models
I'm developing an application using FastAPI and Pydantic, and I'm encountering a circular import issue when trying to define my data models.
Here are the relevant files:
src/schemas/user.py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
from src.schemas.blog import ShowBlog  # Import causing circular dependency

class ShowUser(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str
    blogs: List[ShowBlog]

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str
    password: str

src/schemas/blog.py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from src.schemas.user import ShowUser  # Import causing circular dependency

class Blog(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: str
    user_id: int

class ShowBlog(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    description: str
    written_by: ShowUser

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

When I run the application, I receive the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'ShowBlog' from partially initialized module 'src.schemas.blog' (most likely due to a circular import)

How can I resolve this circular import issue while keeping my FastAPI application structured? Are there best practices for organizing Pydantic models to avoid such problems?

Have you seen https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/postponed_annotations/ ?

If you're on Python 3.9 or newer (and you should be — 3.8 reaches end of life next week —), you can use list[ShowBlog] instead of importing List, which is now deprecated.

@CrazyChucky Oh, this is a nice tip. Thank you

I asked the same question a few days ago. Apparently, there is no obvious way to solve this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79023460/handling-circular-imports-in-pydantic-models-with-fastapi

I haven't used Pydantic and I'm not at a computer, but have you tried from __future__ import annotations and putting the imports in if TYPE_CHECKING blocks? It seems like that should work (and you wouldn't need to use strings for the types then).

I had a similiar problem using SQLModel with fastapi. This is what worked for me: Replace the dependency in one of the schema files with the name in quotations and don't import it there:
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ShowUser(BaseModel):
   username: str
   email: str
   blogs: List["ShowBlog"]

   class Config:
       from_attributes = True


class User(BaseModel):
   username: str
   email: str
   password: str

This seems to work also in your example!

What about from_attributes=True?

I just deleted it on accident, i don't think it changes anything.

One possible solution is to write the name of the model as a string, as @Freshpinguin mentioned.
But I personally prefer to just reorganize models if I encounter such errors.
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Blog(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: str
    user_id: int

class ShowBlog(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    description: str
    written_by: 'ShowUser'

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True


class ShowUser(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str
    blogs: List[ShowBlog]

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

This way, linked models are stored where it enhances readability, or they can be moved to a separate file, like schemas.show, altogether.

This actually may solve the problem; however I wished Blogs and Users related files to be separated
